Is Decimal a lot slower in MacOS Swift than Decimal in Python?
[update]fyi: I did try running the same test below with GMP lib in Swift and it is about 10x faster than Swift Decimal which I imagine the upper bound would be. Still confused why Python Decimal would be 2.5x faster than Swift Decimal.[/update]
I'm running macOS Sonoma 14.5 with Xcode 15.4, Apple M3 Max. I am using Python 3.12. So I wanted to compare performance between Python and Swift Project (Command Line Tool).
I first compared math operations using Double. For Python I see 5 million calculations take 241s:
functions: 100000 calculations: 5000000000 duration: 241187.8740787506 ms cputime: 240905.40899999999 ms

For MacOS using Double for the same number of calculations it will take 1.3 seconds.
functions: 100000 calculations: 5000000000 duration: 1266.797791ms

That is like a 191x improvement! Pretty amazing. It's so much better than I had actually expected that I think I must've done something wrong. I've looked many times and I don't think I have.
Moving on, I tried the same thing with Decimal. I know they're different implementations and not necessarily the same "Decimal" but they both do higher precision maths.
For Python for 200k calculations takes 73 seconds:
functions: 20000 calculations: 200000000 duration: 72631.9727897644 ms cputime: 72520.69300000001 ms pi: 3.141592653589793115997963468544185161590576171875

But for Swift the same 200k calculations takes 186 seconds! And that's with a smaller mantissa.
functions: 20000 calculations: 200000000 duration: 186482.24125ms pi: 3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419

That's about 2.6x slower! I had imagined since the floating point binary arithmetic stuff works so well in Swift that should also translate to Decimal working at some level better in MacOS. I totally did not expect the inverse. It's actually fairly disappointing if true.
I'm not sure if there is any real hope of getting Decimal to work better in Swift but I thought I'd ask just in case I may be doing something wrong here or maybe suggestions for fast arbitrary precision math packages I may want to look up. I did compile my Swift code in Release mode.
I've included my code for Decimal comparison below. (The Double comparison code looks pretty much the same, just with float/Double):
Python
import random
import time
import math
from time import process_time, time
from decimal import *

REPEAT_CALC = 10000
INPUTS_COUNT = 20000

inputs = []
calculations = 0
functions = 0

for i in range(0, INPUTS_COUNT):
    input = (Decimal(random.randint(1, 10)), Decimal(random.randint(1, 10)))
    inputs.append(input)

def calculate(x, y):
    global calculations
    global functions
    Decimal_pi = Decimal(math.pi)
    functions += 1
    hypo = Decimal(0)
    for i in range(0, REPEAT_CALC):
        hypo = (x / Decimal_pi) * (y / Decimal_pi)
        calculations += 1
    return hypo

def get_calculations(inputs):
    solutions = []
    for input in inputs:
        solutions.append(calculate(input[0], input[1]))
    return solutions

time_started = time()
ptime_started = process_time()
solutions = get_calculations(inputs)
ptime_ended = process_time()
time_ended =  time()

print("functions:", functions, "calculations:", calculations, "duration:", (time_ended - time_started)*1000, "ms cputime:", (ptime_ended - ptime_started) * 1000.0, "ms pi:", Decimal(math.pi))


Swift
import Foundation
import Cocoa

let REPEAT_CALC: Int = 10000
let INPUTS_COUNT: Int = 20000

let clock = ContinuousClock()

var inputs: [(Decimal, Decimal)] = [(Decimal, Decimal)]()
inputs.reserveCapacity(INPUTS_COUNT)
var calculations: Int = 0
var functions: Int = 0

for _ in 0 ..< INPUTS_COUNT
{
    inputs.append((Decimal(Int.random(in: 1..<10)), Decimal(Int.random(in: 1..<10))))
}

func calculate(x: Decimal, y: Decimal) -> Decimal
{
    functions += 1
    var hypo: Decimal = 0
    for _ in 0 ..< REPEAT_CALC
    {
        hypo = (x/Decimal.pi) * (y/Decimal.pi)
        calculations += 1
    }
    return hypo
}

func get_calculations(my inputs: [(Decimal, Decimal)]) -> [Decimal]
{
    var solutions: [Decimal] = []
    solutions.reserveCapacity(inputs.count)
    for input in inputs
    {
        solutions.append(calculate(x: input.0, y: input.1))
    }
    return solutions
}

var solutions: [Decimal] = []
let time = clock.measure
{
    solutions = get_calculations(my: inputs)
}
print("functions: \(functions) calculations: \(calculations) duration: \(Double(time.components.seconds) * 1000 + Double(time.components.attoseconds) * 1e-15)ms pi:", Decimal.pi)


btw, you usually don't want to pass a float to Decimal, e.g. when you did Decimal(math.pi)

as an aside, Python float should perform better if you aren't using a global variables. You are essentially looking up/ modifying a dict each time you lookup-up/modify a global variable, that is much costlier than adding two float objects

@juanpa.arrivillaga is there another way to get the Decimal value of pi? That's the way it's done in https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html and the value checks out in print I have above. Thanks for the tip about global! I do see a couple more seconds of improvement.

You are fundamentally misunderstanding the decimal.Decimal construtor, if you pass it a float, it gives you a decimal representation of the float value, which in this case, is not exact. Consider, print(Decimal(0.1)) and print(Decimal(0.25)). If you want a precise value, pass a str object. So compare Decimal('0.25') and Decimal('0.1')

There is some fundamental understanding on the fundamentals of these languages you have to grasp. Python's floats are Objects, just as efficient or inefficient as its Decimals - while the languages will us native CPU types for floats. Keep in mind that most numeric computations in Python are done with libraries like numpy that will use native numbers underneath - however no mainstream CPU has a native Decimal number, so it depends on the better software implementation.

It doesn't. Decimal(math.pi) gives: Decimal('3.141592653589793115997963468544185161590576171875') and pi to a similar precision is: 3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510. If you round it might be accurate at that level of significance, though

@jsbueno I do get that both languages don't use binary floating point arithmetic for their respective Decimal implementations and underneath is some struct is representing the Decimal value to some length of significant digits and doing math in Decimal ways and not using binary math native to the CPU.  But I'm just saying I'd expect the Decimal in MacOS Swift to be comparable to Python Decimal but it is not.

@juanpa.arrivillaga you're right! I was reading the wrong output, my apologies.

Note: Decimal bridges to NSDecimal and is implemented in C (probably in the 20th century). Don't blame Swift.
